# Create a private group in stackexchange

Tags: feature-request

How do I create a private group in this stackExchange? I have more than 100 reputation, I want to create a private group how?

Comment: Akash, what do you mean by "private group" ?  (chat ?)

Comment: A private discussion forum, only restricted members can answer. This is needed for our privacy

Comment: This question should be on http://meta.stackexchange.com/. Explain there with real scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not provide the ability to create private or members-only sites. If you cannot find a Stack Exchange site on your subject of expertise, we have a place called "Area 51" where you can propose one. It's a community-driven process where groups of experts come together to build new Q&A sites that work just like the Salesforce site here. You can read more about that process here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq.